# make an element of a record unique, compared to another xml file

Tags: xslt-3.0

Given two xml files, i need to compare if the combination of TITLEID, and ARTIST, is unique (meaning that in the second file there is not the same combination of TITLEID,ARTIST, existing in the first xml file)

```
<CATALOG>
        <RECORD ID="109">
           <TITLEID>54</TITLEID>
           <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
           <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
           <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
           <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1985</YEAR> </CD>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="187">
           <TITLEID>88</TITLEID>
           <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
           <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
           <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
           <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1988</YEAR> </CD>
         </RECORD>
    </CATALOG>

    second xml:

<CATALOG>
    <RECORD ID="109">
       <TITLEID>54</TITLEID>
       <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1985</YEAR> </CD>
    </RECORD>
     <RECORD ID="187">
       <TITLEID>text ',.</TITLEID>
       <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1988</YEAR> </CD>
     </RECORD>
</CATALOG>
```

So i need to do the following, only for those records that have the following condition true:
TITLEIDARTIST (from xml1) TITLEIDARTIST (from xml2)

i need to make the TITLEIDARTIST combination unique, in the first xml file, adding for instance a digit to the TITLEID (making sure though that this digit addition will not make a new number that will create a new combination that will match the second xml).

SO the desired output would be like (i only need to modify the first xml, and leave untouched the second):

```
<CATALOG>
        <RECORD ID="109">
           <TITLEID>540</TITLEID>
           <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
           <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
           <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
           <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1985</YEAR> </CD>
        </RECORD>
         <RECORD ID="187">
           <TITLEID>88</TITLEID>
           <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
           <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
           <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
           <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
           <YEAR>1988</YEAR> </CD>
         </RECORD>
    </CATALOG>
```

Please note that in the second XML file, in the TITLEID, one may find text, not only digits.

Comment: Do you need to generate the new TITLEID as a number? Or would the value from `generate-id()` (which is an XML ID value e.g. a sequence starting with a letter followed by other letters or digits) suffice?

Comment: And please edit the samples in the question to be well-formed, currently it is not clear whether `CD` contains `RECORD` or the other way around.

Comment: f it is doable, the value from generate-id() (which is an XML ID value e.g. a sequence starting with a letter followed by other letters or digits) would suffice, as long it is not too long enough, since it will be printed as ID sticker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 3 you can use a composite key to identify the elements for which there are duplicates in the secondary document and then generate a new id based on `generate-id()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="doc2">
<CATALOG>
    <RECORD ID="109">
       <TITLEID>54</TITLEID>
       <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </RECORD>
     <RECORD ID="187">
       <TITLEID>text ',.</TITLEID>
       <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
       <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
       <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
       <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
       <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
     </RECORD>
</CATALOG>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="ref" match="RECORD" composite="yes" use="TITLEID, ARTIST"/>

  <xsl:template match="RECORD[key('ref', (TITLEID, ARTIST), $doc2)]/TITLEID">
      <xsl:copy>{generate-id()}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVZ/0

For compactness and self-containedness that example include the secondary document inline but of course you could use the parameter to pass in the document from the outside or change the code to use e.g. `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc($doc2-uri)"/>` with a second parameter to pass in the URI/location of the second document e.g. `<xsl:param name="doc2-uri" as="xs:string">second-doc.xml</xsl:param>`.

Comment: works perfect, only one concern i have, is how one rests assured, that the generate-id() will not by bad chance not create a new same TITLEID, and then we will have two identical TITLEID in the same XML...

Comment: During one run of an XSLT stylesheet, the XSLT/XPath implementation needs to ensure any node has/generates a unique id (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-generate-id) so that value generated should be unique. If you intend to run the XSLT a second time on the output of the first run then using generate-id() is not safe.